# right is not working in position: absolute CSS

Tags: html, css

So I've looked at some similar problem, but I still don't get it. Please take a look on my HTML and CSS sheet:

CSS:

```css
.bottom1Container {
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
}
.bottom1 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 63%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: scale-down;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="bottom1Container">
    <div class="bottom1" style="background:url(/images/bottom1.svg) no-repeat ;"></div>
```

So, as you can see there's already `position: relative` in the parent. But why is this still not working? (btw the bottom1.svg file is an animation svg)

Comment: This is insufficient code and It is not so clear what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I was trying to put the image to the right using this code, but it wouldn't work

Comment: Why do you need right when the element is 100% wide.

Answer (score 0):

When you make it non 100% wide, it will work

```css
.bottom1Container {
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
}
.bottom1 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    object-fit: scale-down;
}

div {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom1Container" style="background-color: gray">
    <div class="bottom1" style="background-color: blue; width: 50%">
        <p>Your div with background image</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But if you only want to position the background-image, try background-position: right;